# How to extract EXIF creation date and set file creation date

Tags: linux, sed, date-time, exif

The transfer of images from IPhone somehow screwed up the file dates. 
I want to set them from EXIF data.

I already found a solution but wasn't able to convert this into a batch job. Feel free to help, maybe other users find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I % sh -c 'touch % -d "$(file %|grep -oP "datetime=\K[^,]*"|sed -e "s/:/-/"|sed -e "s/:/-/")"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this command.

```
identify -verbose <file> |egrep "Image:|exif:DateTimeDigitized:" |sed '{N;s,Image: \(.*\)\n.*exif:DateTimeDigitized: \(.*\),touch -d "\2" \1,}'|sed 's,2017:10:,2017-10-,'
```

I wasn't able to convert this into a batch job because `sed` is required to work on multi-lines which collides somehow with different approaches working on a list (xargs, a simple list...)

Just pipe it to bash to execute or copy & paste.